# Why SQLiteConnection.Update(client) doesn't Update a table entry?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin

I'm solving an error in an Android App that works fine but when I update a client it doesn't make changes in the Database. I'm building a query like:

```
            StringBuilder query= new StringBuilder("PRAGMA encoding = \"UTF-8\"; UPDATE tclientes SET");
            //Building the query...
            query.AppendFormat(" WHERE cli_code = '{0}';", cliente.cli_code);
            Db.Query<tclientes>(query.ToString()); //this in a try-catch
```

It catches no errors nor updates the entry. I've also tried:

```
            Db.Update(cliente);
```

for 'client being an instance of the model, but this triggers the error: "System.NotSupportedException: Cannot update clients: it has no PK at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Update", maybe the value used as a key (cli_code) is not enough? I'm not sure what to do

**Edit:**
I've also tried creating a SQLiteCommand and binding parameters with no result. It works with 'InsertOrUpdate(client)', which is great, but I still don't have an answer to the main question

Comment: How is the table defined?  The 2nd error message is pretty clearly telling you that the table is missing a PK

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

You could refer to the code below about create the table and insert, update the database.

```
var dbpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Mydb.db");
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
        db.CreateTable<Employee>();
        db.CreateTable<Duty>();
        var employee = new Employee
        {
            Name = "Andrew",
            LastName = "Programmer"
        };
        db.Insert(employee);


        var duty1 = new Duty()
        {
            Description = "Project A Management",
            Deadline = new DateTime(2017, 10, 31)
        };

        var duty2 = new Duty()
        {
            Description = "Reporting work time",
            Deadline = new DateTime(2022, 12, 31)
        };

        db.Insert(duty1);
        db.Insert(duty2);

        employee.Duties = new List<Duty> { duty1, duty2 };
        db.UpdateWithChildren(employee);
```

Comment: This will work for an async connection, but I have a singletone SQLiteConnection, I can't call it this way

Comment: I updated my reply. Please check it.